# Display bug file/line in Javascript console in VS Express 2013

Tags: javascript, windows-8, visual-studio-2013, windows

I would like to display the file and the line number where this error occurs and I can't figure out how to do it.
Otherwise is there a way to display a kind of stack trace to know the source of this bug?

[image: Visual studio debugger]

Ideally, I would like to have something similar to Google Chrome debugger:

[image: Error in chrome]

Comment: Are you looking for console.log()

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this..

```
  WinJS.Application.onerror = function (e) {
        // The first argument give us details of the exception:
        var message = e.detail.message;
        var description = e.detail.description;
        var code = e.detail.number;
        var stackTrace = e.detail.stack;
        // ...use console.log() to log your error details
        return true;
    };
```

Comment: This is good when you have a critical error but mine are not critical. they are just kind of "red warnings"

Comment: The image you have posted shows errors.. doesnt it?

Comment: Yep they are in red like errors but my app doesn't crash. So I guess it's kind of important notice but not critical.

Comment: When there is an error(compile time).. your app would not run.. when your app is running and there is an unhandled exception or run time error then it would crash..What s the need to display compile time errors when it is done by the IDE..correct me if Im wrong..

Comment: I didn't find the way to display what file was wrong but this message is not anymore displayed since I've download jquery for win8 apps. So I guess it was linked to an unsafe .append() in jQuery plugin.
Do you see a bit better what kind of error it is?